# Recursion on a function

Tags: python, recursion

I am practicing the recursion in Python. Having trouble with this code, I thought it would print 53, but instead it gives me 56.

```
def add(a):
    if a > 30:
        return 3
    else:
        return a + add(a + 3)
 
print(add(25))
```

At the beginning I thought that the function was being called just once. Is it possible that when `a = 53` the first if statement comes true so it adds the other 3? In that case that would be the answer to `53 + 3 = 56` However, I don't see when the function decided to come back to the first `if` statement.

Comment: Hint: What is fun(31)? What is fun(28)? What is fun(25)?

Comment: I will change the name to add instead of fun to avoid confusion.

Comment: `a` is never 53; it's 25, then 28, then 31.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack looks like:

```
fun(25)
25 + fun(28)
25 + 28 + fun(31)
25 + 28 + 3
```

which resolves to 56

Answer (score 0):

On the first call, `a` is 25.  Therefore `fun(a + 3)` is called.

On the second call, `a` is 28.  Therefore `fun(a + 3)` is called.

On the third call, `a` is 31, so 3 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

fun(31) is 3.

fun(28) is 28+fun(31), which is 31.

fun(25) is 25+fun(28), which is 56.

Answer (score 0):

Since `add` is a pure function, you can use equational reasoning to trace how the function evaluates at each step.

```
add(25) == 25 + add(28)      # 25 > 30 is false
        == 25 + 28 + add(31) # 28 > 30 is false
        == 25 + 28 + 3       # 31 > 30 is true
        == 53 + 3
        == 56
```